# Why ( Math.Pow(2, x) & (2^y + 2^z + 2^i) ) is always return 0

Tags: c#, operators

Like the title, I don't understand why that expression is always true?

Here is the detail:

```
// x, y, z, t is always different with each other
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
int z = 3;

int total = (int)Math.Pow(2, x) + (int)Math.Pow(2, y) + (int)Math.Pow(2, z);

int t = 4; // or any number which is not x, y, z

int result = (int)Math.Pow(2, t) & total;
```

result is always = 0

Can someone explain it please?

Here is some example how to apply this expression into my code :P.

I have list of day of week. I want to pick a day to go out with my friend. If today is not picked, ill not go anywhere :D

Some pre-defined value:
Day:  Mon-Tue-Wed-Thu-Fri-Sat-Sun
Value: 1-2-3-4-5-6-7

I will pick Mon, Tue and Fri save value into my DB.

Instead of saving {1, 2, 5}, ill save 38 (2^1 + 2^2 + 2^5).

If today is Tue, I will check like this: 2^2 & 38 = 4. 4 is # 0 so today is the day, go out.

If today is Wed, I will check like this: 2^3 & 38 = 0. So today isn't, go to bed

Comment: its mistaken, i edited it :P

Comment: Note that with a integer `a` between `0` and `31`, instead of `(int)Math.Pow(2, a)` you can use just `1 << a` or `(1 << a)`. Maybe that can help you see the answer to your question?

Comment: And if `a` is over 31 the `(int)` casting would mess up the output of `Math.Pow` anyway.

Comment: yes, its just example so i put (int) (its faster than long in typing :P)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To really understand what is happening here, you must first understand *binary*, because what you're doing with the `&` is a [bitwise-and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

So, in our normal way of writing numbers, we use the decimal system, or base-10, system. You count from 0 to 9 and then prepend another number to indicate an "overflow": 10. In binary, or base-2, we can only count 0 or 1, before we must prepend another number. So, to count from 0 to 4 for example, we have binary: 0 = 0, 1 = 1, 2 = 10, 3 = 11, 4 = 100. Each one of these zeros or ones are bits, which are easy for a computer to calculate with since it can represent them as a transistor switching either on or off.

What you're doing here is generating numbers that are basically 1's with a lot of zeros in binary. You'll notice that if you do 10^x (`Math.Pow(10, x)`) you get multiples of 10 with a lot of zeros: 10, 100, 1000, 10000, etc.

2^x (`Math.Pow(2, x)`) does the same thing: it generates the **binary** numbers 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000. In our decimal notation those binary numbers translate to 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 respectively.

Now what the `&` (bitwise AND) does, is return the binary code in which all the ones on the left are also one the right. So, say you have **binary**: 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 = 1 + 10 + 100 = 111.

And you do a bitwise operation with 2^4 on the left, which is 1000. So you're asking if 1000 & 0111 (you can add as many zeros to the left of any binary code, just as you could with a decimal number: 00100 is still just one hundred). This evaluates to 0000 = 0.

You noticed that when t is either x, y, or z, it returns either x, y or z respectively, effectively acting like a filter, because, well: 0010 & 0111 = 0010 (there are both ONES in the second position). A more complex example would be 0110 1100 & 1100 0101 = 0100 0100.

There; now you can calculate your computer does :-)

Comment: this is more detail than Joachim Isaksson's one

Answer (score 4):

If you see it as binary, and *as long as x,y,z are distinct numbers*, the result of;

```
(int)Math.Pow(2, x) + (int)Math.Pow(2, y) + (int)Math.Pow(2, z)
```

is an integer with bit x, y and z (and only those bits) set.

```
(int)Math.Pow(2, t) & total
```

...checks if bit t is set. As long as t is distinct from x, y, z, it won't be.

Answer (score 3):

It's because:

```
total = 14
Math(2,4) = 16

16 and 14 = 0
```

it's binary operation!

```
16 = (10000) binary
14 = (01110) binary
```

no common bit between them so `and` will return 0. If you expected othere result maybe you wanted to do `or`?

```
16 or 14 = 30
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but i think its not an answer. I known it is always return 0. I need something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem. Its always true, we dont need to prove it again =.=

Comment: @Trung do you mean, you need to check if a^2+b^2=c^2?

Comment: nope, its just something about how ill manage my data in DB. Ill edit my question.

Answer (score 3):

Think of `x`, `y`, `z` and `t` as bit positions - you're doing a bitwise `&` which will clear any bits which aren't set in *both* operands, and 2<sup>t</sup> will *only* have the `t`th bit set.

So if `x`, `y` and `z` are all different, 2<sup>x</sup> + 2<sup>y</sup> + 2<sup>z</sup> will have bits `x`, `y` and`z` set, and 2<sup>t</sup> will have bit `t` set... so performing a bitwise AND operation on the two results will always give 0.

Now your original claim (which didn't specify that `x`, `y` and `z` were different) isn't *quite* true, because if `x` and `y` are the same (for example) the addition can effectively give you a different bit. (Addition of integer values each of which has just a single bit set is only equivalent to bitwise-OR if the operands all have different bits set.)

For example:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 2;
int z = 10; // Ignore this, effectively

// 2^2 + 2^2 + 2^10 == 2^3 + 2^10
int total = (int)Math.Pow(2, x) + (int)Math.Pow(2, y) + (int)Math.Pow(2, z);

int t = 3;
int result = (int)Math.Pow(2, t) & total; // result is now 8
```

Comment: @Trung: It would have been better to leave it, or add an edit - otherwise you're effectively invalidating the answers you've got so far.

Answer (score 3):

Its a binary comparison (`&` compares each position in the two numbers and returns 1 if both are 1):

```
10000 // 16 in binary
01110 // 14 in binary
00000 // 14 & 16 = 0
```

Use some other value there instead, and you will get a different value. Take, for example 6 and 10:

```
00101  // 6 in binary
01110  // 14 in binary
00100  // 6 and 14 = 8
```

**PS:** You can experiment with this type of math using the calculator on your PC by choosing *View > Programmer*, and switching between Bin and Dec on the left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

& Does binary AND operation and hence binary ADD of 16 and 14 is 0

```
   10000
 & 01110
 ------- 
   00000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
total = 14
Math(2,4) = 16
```

So

```
(10000) // 16
(01110) // 14
(00000) // 16 & 14 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(int)Math.Pow(2, t) = (2^4)base 10 = (10000)base 2
total = (2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1)base 10 =  (01110)base 2
```

**&** is **binary AND** and can be considered as multiplication between every bits

therefore

```
1*0 = 0
0*1 = 0
0*1 = 0
0*1 = 0
0*0 = 0
(int)Math.Pow(2, t) & total = (10000)base 2 & (01110)base 2 = (00000)base 2 = 0
```

Assume we have

```
total1 =  (10001)base 2
```

then

```
(int)Math.Pow(2, t) & total1 = (10000)base 2 & (10001)base 2 = (10000)base 2 = (16)base 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing a binary operation by using &.
This & is equal to bitwise AND (AND gate) . AND works like this.

```
When 1 & 1 =1
when 1 & 0 = 0
when 0 & 1 = 0
when 0 & 0 = 0
```

when matching values met it will output 1 , else it will output 0.[Check how and works](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/boolean1.htm)

```
1001
1110
------
1000  
------
```

so value of binary 1000 is 8

Comment: hhmm, i think you are some mistaken here, cause sometime, with another values, it will be not only 0 or 1. Ex: t = 3, result will be 8

Comment: yes exactlly my friend.
when t = 3 it`s 9 & 14. Which means
1001
1110
------
1000
so the value of 1000 is 8. Please refer thye modified answer